# Changing fonts and values in html from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form in html and I want to change the text from 'champions league trivia' to 'Manchester' when I click the button. It changes cut only for a second and then changes back to 'champions league trivia'. I cant figure out why its changing back. Any ideas?

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="quiz.js" ></script>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkscript()">
    <h1>Choose a Quiz</h1>

    <p><input type="radio" name="Radio" value="1" /><font size="5"
    color="#0033CC" id="cl">Champions League Trivia</font><br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="2" /><font size="5"
    color="#CC0000" id="epl">English Premier League Trivia</font><br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="Radio" value="3" /><font size="5"
    color="#660033" id="ll">La Liga Trivia</font><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go" onclick="quizRun()" /></p>
    </form>
    <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the javascript

```
function quizRun()
{
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var choice = 0;
if (inputs[0].checked) {
        choice = 1;
        var cl = document.getElementById('cl');
        cl.textContent = 'Manchester';
}
if (inputs[1].checked) {
        choice = 2;

}
if (inputs[2].checked) {
        choice = 3;
}
}
function checkscript()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=0, l=inputs.length; i<l; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].name === "Radio" && inputs[i].checked) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your button is of `type = "submit"`. When you submit a form, the page is being reloaded and the original value returns.

If you don't care to submit the form, just change your "Go" button to `type = "button"`

Answer (score 1):

I tried your script and I found this: the value changes but the form is submitted, so the page reloads and the texts changes back.

Comment: Ok I figured that might be the problem. Is there a way around that? I dont want it to reload.

Comment: onsubmit="return checkscript()", why do you return true if you don't want it?

Comment: Yeah it should always return false. I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cl.innerHTML = 'Manchester';`

**Edit:**

Your Form tag has no action so the page probably refreshes causing the original value to return. Adding a `return false` or `preventDefault` to your form submit event will prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried the code myself, innerHTML or innerText doesn't work neither @ben fossen
So the only reason why this could appen is beacuse the value actually changes, but then the form submits and resets the value